# A value of type "class" can't be assigned to a variable of type "class"?

Tags: flutter, dart

An error occured after I convert a map into an object:

```
 Error: A value of type 'FormData/*1*/' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FormData/*2*/'.
formFunctions.dart:42
- 'FormData/*1*/' is from 'package:flexsystem_appclient/widgets/formFunctions.dart' ('lib/widgets/formFunctions.dart').
formFunctions.dart:1
- 'FormData/*2*/' is from 'package:flexsystem_appclient/widgets/FormFunctions.dart' ('lib/widgets/FormFunctions.dart').
formFunctions.dart:1
    FormData formData = pageLoader.formData;
```

The FormData class is the exact same one, however, the file is different (formFunctions vs FormFunctions, notice the capitals)

I have checked the directory and no FormFunction.dart was ever found, only formFunction.dart:
[image]

I will provide more info if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports are case sensitive in Dart even if filenames on Windows are not. So in the following example, Dart will see these two files as different files with the same declarations which gives you a conflict.

```dart
import 'package:flexsystem_appclient/widgets/formFunctions.dart';
import 'package:flexsystem_appclient/widgets/FormFunctions.dart';
```

Check your project and make sure you are using the correct casing in the name for all files you are importing so they actually match the exact name of your files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found in some older code that has the capitalisation, not sure why it worked before and not now? But it is fixed regardless.